# Adding frequency column to df in R

Tags: r, frequency

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and thousands of rows. I need to calculate the frequency of variable #3, and for that I used  `table` function in R. Problem is, `table` returns a separate 2 column table (the variable on which the frequency is being calculated and the calculated frequency), and no reference to the original dataframe, so I can't relate the frequency results to the other columns on the dataframe.

I've tried 2 approaches with no luck (both solutions would work for me, though one can be more efficient than the other):

1. adding and ID column that refers to the original dataframe (at least for th first occurrence of the factor being considered for frequency) to the output of `table` (in my case, would be something like applying `cbind` with th frequency table and column #1 of the original df,  but this won't work as both objects has different # of rows)
2. adding a new column to the original dataframe with the the frequency of a specific column (I've tried `mutate` with no luck either)

Some example data:

```
dfg <- data.frame(f=c(1,2,3,4,5),v1=c("a","b","b","c","c"),v2=c("3r","3r","3r","gh","y"))
dfg  
    f v1 v2
    1 1  a 3r
    2 2  b 3r
    3 3  b 3r
    4 4  c gh
    5 5  c  y
```

Solution 1) would be:

```
     3r gh  y 
     3  1  1 
 f   1  4  5
```

Solution 2) would be:

```
f v1 v2  freq(v2)
1 1  a 3r  3
2 2  b 3r  3
3 3  b 3r  3
4 4  c gh  1
5 5  c  y  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dfg <- data.frame(f=c(1,2,3,4,5),v1=c("a","b","b","c","c"),v2=c("3r","3r","3r","gh","y"))

#1
library(dplyr)

dfg %>% group_by(v2) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            f = first(f)) %>%
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(1)
#>   3r gh y
#> n  3  1 1
#> f  1  4 5

#2
transform(dfg, freq_v2 = ave(dfg$f, dfg$v2, FUN = length))
#>   f v1 v2 freq_v2
#> 1 1  a 3r       3
#> 2 2  b 3r       3
#> 3 3  b 3r       3
#> 4 4  c gh       1
#> 5 5  c  y       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You were already quite close. Now, you just need to link the frequency table back to the table, using `v2` as key:

```
dfg$v3 = table(dfg$v2)[dfg$v2]
```

This does the trick.

Since a frequency table is just a named vector, you can use the keys to reference entries from the frequency table. And `v2` naturally has all the keys.